# Two questions with ImageString: Bold words and Newlines PHP

Tags: php, string, image, newline, bold

Well I'm trying to write a text in a image and I have this:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$font = 4;
$width = ImageFontWidth($font) * strlen($string);
$height = ImageFontHeight($font);

$im = @imagecreate($width,$height);
$background_color = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 255, 255, 255, 127);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0,0); 
imagestring($im, $font, 0, 0, utf8_decode($string), $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

And the string:

```
$string = "Hello, My name is Ikillnukes and I'm trying to do a newline with PHP.";
```

Well I want to do this with the output:

**Normal output**: Hello, My name is Ikillnukes and I'm trying to do a newline with PHP.

**That I want:**

Hello, My name is Ikillnukes and

I'm trying to do a newline with PHP.

How can I do this?

And one more thing... I want to add some bold text to the string how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First at all, `imagestring` does not do automatic word wrapping. You have to do it on your own.

That means that you need to know how long in pixels a specific string is. Here is [`imagettfbox`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) your friend.

In the documentation for `imagettfbox` is a good and comprehensive example how to auto-wrap strings to match the image width: [Example by a2hansolo in the PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php#101537).

For your problem with the bold writing, take a look at the documentation about [`imagettftext`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagettftext.php), especially the [example by mirza_aqueel_qau](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagettftext.php#105073).